# How to define optional text in Gherkin containing a parameter?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I have the following two steps

- When I run a report every **week** on **Sunday** at **22:00**
- When I run a report every **day** at **22:00**

where the bold text are parameters.

How can I change the 'on **Sunday**' to become optional ?

```
When(/^I run a report every (.+) on (.+) at (\d{1,2}:\d{2})/, (every, day, time) => {
  console.log('every %s for day %s at %s', every, day, time);
});

When(/^I run a report every (.+) at (\d{1,2}:\d{2})/, (every, time) => {
  console.log('every %s at %s', every, time);
});
```

I tried to set parenthesis around the `on (.+)` to be like `(on (.+))?`, but this makes the the parameter **Sunday** before to **on Sunday**.

How can I define the text as optional, but keep the original word as parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `(on (.+))?` means you end up with one more parameter to your step definition. This new parameter is useless, and honestly it only serves to complicate your step.

I would keep them as two separate steps. Any code those steps share in common should be refactored into another function.

Making `on Sunday` optional will make your code terse and harder to understand. Gherkin should be easy to read. So should your step definitions. There are plenty of other code reuse techniques at your disposal that allow you to write readable and DRY code.